# R Markdown printing different table to environment

Tags: r, dataframe, r-markdown

I have created a number of data frames in an R script. One of those is `first_year_takeup`, and another is `first_year_takeup2`.

Both of these are created using the same methods, and produce the correct output results in the Global Environment.

```
> print(first_year_takeup)
First.Year
1       0.241
2       0.344
3       0.447
4       0.551
5       0.632
6       0.713
7       0.793
8       0.816
9       0.839
10      0.862

> print(first_year_takeup2)
First.Year
1       0.172
2       0.218
3       0.264
4       0.310
5       0.436
6       0.689
7       0.747
8       0.862
9       0.862
10      0.862
```

However, when I try printing these directly in an RMarkdown file, `first_year_takeup2` prints correctly (on the right), but `first_year_takeup` (on the left) prints entirely incorrectly.

[image: first_year_takeup on the left and first_year_takeup2 on the right]

It is taking data from another dataframe variable and repeating this multiple times, before seemingly extrapolating randomly from row 8. Is there any common reasons why this could happen?

This is the same for three other instances of the same paired variables - both show correctly in the global environment but one instance always prints incorrectly through markdown.

I've tried changing variable names, removing all other rmarkdown tables, deleting the environment and history, restarting the R session, but nothing has helped so far.

----------------------------------Edit-------------------------------------------

I have a dataset, `new_data` which has been subset from a larger dataset.

```
   Bus.Use                   Pay.Method Bus.Pass.Max Bus.Freq.Total
1      Yes     Single/Return/Day ticket          299            3.0
2      Yes           Pack of 10 tickets          399            1.5
3      Yes     Single/Return/Day ticket          299            3.0
4      Yes           Pack of 10 tickets          399            5.0
5      Yes Yearly Pass (term-time only)          499            9.0
6      Yes       Yearly Pass (12-month)         600+           22.0
7      Yes     Single/Return/Day ticket          299            1.5
8       No                                         0            0.0
9      Yes     Single/Return/Day ticket          199            3.0
10     Yes     Single/Return/Day ticket          299            1.5
11      No                                         0            0.0
12     Yes           Pack of 10 tickets          299            3.0
13     Yes     Single/Return/Day ticket          199            5.0
14      No                                       199            0.0
15     Yes       Yearly Pass (12-month)          299            7.0
16     Yes     Single/Return/Day ticket          199            1.5
17     Yes           Pack of 10 tickets         600+            3.0
18     Yes           Pack of 10 tickets            0            5.0
19      No                                       199            0.0
20     Yes     Single/Return/Day ticket          299            3.0
21     Yes     Single/Return/Day ticket          199            7.0
22     Yes     Single/Return/Day ticket          299            3.0
23     Yes           Pack of 10 tickets          399            1.5
24     Yes           Pack of 10 tickets          299            3.0
25     Yes           Pack of 10 tickets           99            3.0
26     Yes     Single/Return/Day ticket          199            5.0
27     Yes           Pack of 10 tickets          199            3.0
28     Yes           Pack of 10 tickets          199           15.0
29     Yes           Pack of 10 tickets          299            3.0
```

I obtain two variables from this dataset as follows:

```
first_year_300_bus_pass <- new_data %>%
  filter(Bus.Use == 'Yes') %>%
  filter(!Pay.Method %in% c('Yearly Pass (12-month)', 'Yearly Pass (term-time only)')) %>%
  filter(!Bus.Pass.Max %in% c('600+', '599', '499', '399')) %>%
  summarize(Mean = mean(Bus.Freq.Total))
```

and

```
first_year_7_bus_pass <- new_data %>%
  filter(Bus.Use == 'Yes') %>%
  filter(!Pay.Method %in% c('Yearly Pass (12-month)', 'Yearly Pass (term-time only)')) %>%
  filter(Bus.Freq.Total < 7) %>%
  summarize(Mean = mean(Bus.Freq.Total))
```

In the Global environment, the results I get are 3.97 and 3.025 respectively.

However, in RMarkdown, the results I get printing these variables are 3.75 and 3.025 respectively.

The 3.75 result appears to come from the first result if the Bus.Pass.Max filter is ignored?

Maybe this will help in reproducing the results.

Comment: Delete the environment and history one time and rerun the code. It should fix.

Comment: You need to extract just the code that creates those data frames and the final printed table, put that (or a subset of it) in its own R Markdown file, then show it to us.  We can't diagnose what we can't see.

Comment: I have added an edit above with some reproducible code.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the environment and history one time and rerun the code. It should fix.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I had already cleared the environment and restarted the R session multiple times. I have now also tried deleting the history but there is no change.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question does not include a reproducible example we can't replicate the error, but we can print the two vectors in a table using `knitr::kable()` as follows.

First the Rmd file:

````
---
title: "printVectors"
author: "lg"
date: "5/10/2020"
output:
  word_document: default
  html_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```



```{r createData,eval = TRUE, echo = FALSE}
library(knitr)
text1 <- "row first_year_takeup
1       0.241
2       0.344
3       0.447
4       0.551
5       0.632
6       0.713
7       0.793
8       0.816
9       0.839
10      0.862"

first_year_takeup <- read.table(text = text1,header = TRUE)[2]

text2 <- "row first_year_takeup2
1       0.172
2       0.218
3       0.264
4       0.310
5       0.436
6       0.689
7       0.747
8       0.862
9       0.862
10      0.862"

first_year_takeup2 <- read.table(text = text2,header = TRUE)[2]

combined <- data.frame(first_year_takeup,first_year_takeup2)

```

## Print the table

`r kable(combined)`
````

...and the output when knit to Microsoft Word:

[image]

Comment: I have added an edit above with some reproducible code.